# How to decide on which $\ n$-th term should I start the sum of a Fourier series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, fourier-series

I have recently started to study Fourier series and I have the following function:

$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
 1&\text{if}\,& 0\leq x\leq \pi  \\
 -1&\text{if}\,& \pi<x\leq 2\pi\\
\end{cases}
$

Where:

$a_0=0$
,$a_n=0$
,$b_n=\frac {2}{\pi}$$(\frac {1-(-1)^n}{n}$)

Given that even $b_n$s are equal to zero, I understand that I should have two choices for, somehow, including the odd ones:

1)

Let $b_{2n+1}=\frac {2}{\pi}$$(\frac {2}{2n+1}$)

And so:

$f(x)=\sum^\infty_0\frac {2}{\pi}$$(\frac {2}{2n+1})sin((2n+1)x) $

1)

Let $b_{2n-1}=\frac {2}{\pi}$$(\frac {2}{2n-1}$)

And so:

$f(x)=\sum^\infty_1\frac {2}{\pi}$$(\frac {2}{2n-1})sin((2n-1)x) $

Now, I don't grasp the reasoning of starting the sum of the Fourier series on 0 or 1 on either case depending on how I want to express the odd ones, and neither the whole reasoning of "including" the odd ones. I am sure that it's something basic and it may even go further than series and sums.

Any help is welcome :)

Comment: You can do either. In numerics it's more efficient to not add in anything that's going to turn out to be zero, but in analysis it doesn't really matter. You just have to be careful about notation, so that you don't get confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function
$$1-(-1)^n=\begin{cases} 2& \text{for odd } n\\
0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
So you can emit all even $b_n$. As to the sum starting at $0$ and $1$ being different, you just have to ensure that every odd number is included. So when $n=0$ we get $2n+1=1$ whereas for $2n-1$ we need to start at $n=1$ for $2n-1=1$.